# how many notifications can an android app have?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, push

I have thought that any android app can have only one alive notification.

But I now read in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) that:

`You call cancelAll(), which removes all of the notifications you previously issued.`

meaning there can be multiple notification living at the same time?

Comment: why downovte? please explain

Comment: I agree, there was no need for a down-vote. Therefore I've up-voted you back up. :)

Answer (score 0):

to my mind , yes. but,
You need to add a unique ID to each of the notifications so that they do not combine with each other.

```
 private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID =1;
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  
        manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Comment: and how do i avoid collision with IDs from other apps? btw on what do you base your answer? on the pure fact that we need to have unique id?

Comment: why do u want avoid collision with IDs from other apps? notifications of other aps are in another window, will not interfere.

Comment: the notificationManager doesn't control notification from all apps and put them into one queue?